# Combine data from 5 different databases in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've 5x databases for 5x websites - each database has 2 tables that represent users in an HTML5 game.

Right now, I'm doing a UNION of 2 tables from ONE database. This is what I'm doing for that:

```
    $query = "SELECT email, SUM(score) as score, username
FROM
(
    (SELECT play2helpdb.users.email, play2helpdb.users.score, play2helpdb.users.username FROM play2helpdb.users)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT scoreboard.yum.email, scoreboard.yum.score, scoreboard.yum.name FROM scoreboard.yum)
) AS tt
GROUP BY email ORDER BY score DESC";
```

Now, how do I extend this query for 4 other databases? I basically want to UNION all this data and display in a table using FOREACH.

Kindly help me out here.

EDIT:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: First, important question - are the other databases on the same server? It looks like you are already querying more than one database (play2helpdb and scoreboard). So you already have that down. If you are trying to do a union across database servers, then the answer is "nope".

Comment: oracle has the idea of dblink looks like mysql has something similiar  called Federated engine to allow you to query across dbs. https://programmer.ink/think/use-of-dblink-in-mysql.html.  however what might be easier is to just make a class. connect to each db individually and append the rows to that object

Comment: I will amend my previous "nope" to say, "not without effort that is likely not warranted."

Comment: It's the same database with different schemas, if you could call it.

I'm basically looking to see if someone can show me how I can UNION 2 tables for each database and combine the final result..

Comment: You are already creating a union between multiple schema, which is why I am confused.

Comment: Yes - but it's all within the same database. I've same schemas in other databases too. So I basically want to merge all their data and show it in a table. The above example simply merges different schemas from same database.

Comment: `play2helpdb` is one database, `scoreboard` is another. You can add in any other databases with the same qualifiers.

Comment: Edited my main post and added screenshots of 3 of the databases that has multiple schemas. play2helpdb is a schema in database A, play2work is a schema in database B.

I want to merge them.

Comment: Are you searching for a pure MySQL implementation, or one that involves PHP? In both cases, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Either works for me.  And honestly, I've no idea how to go about it either. Which is what I'm looking for, someone to tell me / show me how I can go about it. Since I've never encountered a scenario like this before.

Comment: Why not gather all data seperately (by querying one database at a time), and then merge the results in PHP code?

Comment: One of the reasons I'm using UNION is, because if there is playerA@gmail.com in both scoreboard & play2helpdb, I'm combining the scores.

I want the same done when I'm fetching data from 5 databases, so if playerA@gmail.com is in all 5 databases, I want the score to add up cumulatively. 

If you could show me an example of merging the results in PHP, please do so..